# Make table's td's take up full width?

Tags: css, html-table

I have a table. With CSS I've set the width of table, tbody and tr to be 100%, and with firebug I can see this is working.

Can I make the td's take up the full available width?

Comment: all tds in a row (tr tag) automatically fill the whole table, what do you mean?

Comment: `td { width: [100% / no. of TDs]; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the number of columns you use in the table,   and assigning width will show the occupancy of that respective td to its allocated width